# How to use Model for QCombobox

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qcombobox, qabstractitemmodel

I want to use  `QCombobox`  as a the `Combobox` of `Swing` in `Java`. So i need to  use  `Model` for  holding my object. How can i  hold my object in QCombobox. (I think that I should hold  data in Model because `QCombobox` was designed according to MVC Pattern ... )
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depending on what you want to display with your `QComboBox`, you'll need to write your own model, inheriting `QAbstractListModel`, reimplementing `rowCount()`and `data()`.

Then, use `QComboBox::setModel()` to make the `QComboBox` display it.

If you just want to display strings, you can use a [`QStringListModel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlistmodel.html), provided with Qt.

Comment: Where placed the data (not text) in subclassed model? `QComboBox::model()->index(row, 1)`?

Answer (score 5):

You can add a model to your `QCombobox` by using the [`setModel`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qcombobox.html#setModel) function. You can use a predefined model or create your own by inheriting from [`QAbstractItemModel`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qabstractitemmodel.html).

Your model will contain your object to separate display from data.

Answer (score 2):

Qt uses a simplified version of MVC which only has the Model / View parts.

You can use one of the provided subclasses of [QAbstractItemModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html) if you don't need any specialized behaviour, which one to use depends on whether you keep your data in a file system or a data structure in memory.

You should read up the whole section on [model/view programming](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html) in the Qt documentation.